# Parsing of my own SQL Request in Php

Tags: php, mysql, parsing

At the moment I'm making a php program that can take a SQL Request with a `left join` (only two table) the goal is to display them and to edit them. The problem is that if I want to edit them I have to know where the variable comes from (which table...) and i would like to parse my request for know it.

```
SELECT users.login, users_info.linkedin, users.password, users.region, users.email, users.business, users.firstname, users.name, users.version, users.updatable, users.bodyshop_id, users.mac, users.register_date, users.lastvisite_date , users_info.address1, users_info.address2, users_info.address3, users_info.zip, users_info.cellphone, users_info.phone, users_info.direct_dial_phone, users_info.birthday, users_info.date_in, users_info.date_out, users_info.picture_private, users_info.picture_public, users_info.bodyshop, users_info.enterprise, users_info.department, users_info.job, users_info.facebook, users_info.twitter, users_info.instagram
FROM users
LEFT JOIN users_info ON users.id = users_info.id
```

So I just want to create a function that take for example "login" as parameter and return me "users" or linkedin would return me users_info. Do you know a proper way for doing it in php ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I did it like that thanks for helped !

```
public function getTableWithField($field) {

    $tableName1 = "users";
    $tableName2 = "users_info";

    $pos = strpos($this->SQLCMD, $field);

    $tryOne = substr($this->SQLCMD, $pos - strlen($tableName1) - 1, strlen($tableName1));
    $tryTwo = substr($this->SQLCMD, $pos - strlen($tableName2) - 1, strlen($tableName2));

    if ($tableName1 == $tryOne)
        return $tableName1;

    else if ($tableName2 == $tryTwo)
        return $tableName2;

    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.login, users.password, users.region, users.email, users.business, users.firstname, users.name, users.version, users.updatable, users.bodyshop_id, users.mac, users.register_date, users.lastvisite_date , users_info.address1, users_info.address2, users_info.address3, users_info.zip, users_info.cellphone, users_info.phone, users_info.direct_dial_phone, users_info.birthday, users_info.date_in, users_info.date_out, users_info.picture_private, users_info.picture_public, users_info.bodyshop, users_info.enterprise, users_info.department, users_info.job, users_info.facebook, users_info.twitter, users_info.linkedin, users_info.instagram
FROM users as users 
LEFT JOIN users_info as users_info ON users.id = users_info.id
WHERE user.you_field_name = your_condition
```

Comment: Just want to parse my own sql request not to make a new one :(

Comment: Sorry, It not a new one. Bro

Comment: if you have a doubts kindly send your where condition value. i will work and reply.

Answer (score 0):

The most modern syntax to connect mysql in php today is using of PDO. File `index.php`, for example:

```
<?php
        class ConnectPDO {

            private $db_name = 'my_db_name';
            private $db_login = 'root';
            private $db_password = '12345678';
            private $host = 'localhost';
            private $opt = [
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
            ];
            public $connection = null;

            function __construct() {
                $this->connection = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->db_name . ';charset=utf8', $this->db_login, $this->db_password, $this->opt);
            }
        }



    $c=new ConnectPDO();

    $params=array();
    $params['login']='Frodo';

    $prepared=$c->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login=:login");
    $prepared->execute($params);
    // fetching data array
    $data=$prepared->fetchAll();

    // view into browser
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
    echo '</pre>';
```

To prevent injections and to use best practice coding well known practice is to use prepare and execute methods. You can install [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org) fast on windows and test this code. Working folder is `/xampp/htdocs`.

This parameters need to by changed by your credentials.

```
private $db_name = 'my_db_name';
            private $db_login = 'root';
            private $db_password = '12345678';
            private $host = 'localhost';
```

Comment: Whut ? I already did it. Just want a function like getTableName($field) if I do getTableName("password", mySQLRequest)-> return "users" and getTableName("linkedIn", mySQLRequest)-> return "users_info"

Answer (score 0):

Use `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);` to get your data in numeric indexed array, then use `$stmt->getColumnMeta($col_num);` to get info about a column in question.